# MongoDB query with multiple search terms(regexes) in c# with 10gens driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

If we have

```
Blog{
  Name 'Blog1'
  Tags ['testing','visual-studio','2010','c#']
}
Blog{
  Name 'Blog2'
  Tags ['parallel','microsoft','c#']
}
```

Via the console we can execute and find all blog posts that contains some of the provided tags:

```
db.BlogPost.find({ 'Tags' : { '$regex' : ['/^Test/', '/^microsoft/', '/^visual/', '/^studio/', '/^c#/'] } });
```

How can we write the same query in c# 10gens driver ?
Is there any alternative if it can not be written via the 10gens c# driver ?

Query.Match only support one regex. Can we provide him multiple regexes, or we should combine

```
Query.Or(Query.Match("Test"), Query.Match("Micro"), Query.Match("Visual"))
```

I've managed to solve it with 
I've managed to do it with

```
{ "$or" : [{ "Tags" : /^programm/i }, { "Tags" : /^microsoft/i }, { "Tags" : /^visual/i }, { "Tags" : /^studio/i }, { "Tags" : /^assert/i }, { "Tags" : /^2010/i }, { "Tags" : /^c#/i }] }
```

But something tells me that this is an ugly hack that may result in performance issues. What do you think guys ?

The final answer to the problem can be found on:
[Official mongodb forum](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/a097960b056b42a?hl=en)

Comment: That actually won't quite work. In the console to use regular expression literals, you shouldn't quote your regexps -- in other words, use `/^Test/` instead of `'/^Test/'`

Comment: The provided query works when execute via mongo console. The problem is that i can not create mongo query via the c# driver that will support multikeyword regex search.

Comment: @MarjanNikolovski how did you solved it? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the MongoDB c# driver should automatically do the right thing with instances of [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

So you should be able to build the exact same query, except that you would use instances of Regex for ^Test, ^microsoft, ^visual, etc instead of strings.

Comment: It is not a problem to construct the regex, the problem is how to construct array of regexes and use Query.Match